# MSBuild does not build solution file because of mismatching package name

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, bamboo, makeappx

I am trying to build a large UWP project with around 50 solutions using MSBuild on Bamboo. I'm facing this issue and I don't really know what I should do to fix it. The project is built successfully on Visual Studio 2017 but it failed on MSBuild.
Here is the complaint that I received.

```
 MakeAppx : error : Error info: error 80080204: The package with file name "xxxxxx.ParseTestTool_1.1.5.0_x64.appx" and package full name "fd60938b-922a-40a4-84f3-19300a655ed3_1.1.5.0_x64__1npyqggg1xza8" is not valid in the bundle because it has a different package family name than other packages in the bundle. The expected package name is Nameoftheproject.NameoftheProject. [E:\Win10-Auto-Test2\builds\AV-AWDV-BP\xxxxxx-windows\src\dashboard\xxxxxx.Dashboard\xxxxxx.Dashboard.csproj]
11-Jan-2018 20:22:19      MakeAppx : error : Bundle creation failed. [E:\Win10-Auto-Test2\builds\AV-AWDV-BP\xxxxxx-windows\src\dashboard\xxxxxx.Dashboard\xxxxxx.Dashboard.csproj]
11-Jan-2018 20:22:19      MakeAppx : error : 0x80080204 - The specified package format is not valid: The package manifest is not valid. [E:\Win10-Auto-Test2\builds\AV-AWDV-BP\xxxxxxx-windows\src\dashboard\xxxxxx.yyyyyyyy\xxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.csproj]
```

So, why does solution building not work? What is wrong here? What should I fix in MSBuild command-line or .cjproj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error info: error 80080204: The package with file name  and package full name  is not valid in the bundle because it has a different package family name than other packages in the bundle.

According to the error, it seems you add more than one UWP project to your solution, and then try to create a bundle. If yes, you will get this error.

To resolve this issue, open each project file and add the following properties at the end of the first `<PropertyGroup>` element:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Or

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, remove the AppxBundle msbuild argument from the build step.

See the [Set up automated builds for your UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#set-up-a-continuous-integration-ci-build) for more detailed info.

Hope this helps.